# Use parsedown classes static

Tags: php, parsedown

On my code I use all my classes static like: `Parsedown::text('text');` and if I try to use it like that it gives me an error message "Using $this when not in object context ", but I can't figure out how to use Parsedown like this cause I can only use it instantiated like:

```
$Parsedown = new Parsedown();
echo $Parsedown->text('text');
```

Code for function text

```
    function text($text)
    {
        # make sure no definitions are set
        $this->DefinitionData = array();

        # standardize line breaks
        $text = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $text);

        # remove surrounding line breaks
        $text = trim($text, "\n");

        # split text into lines
        $lines = explode("\n", $text);

        # iterate through lines to identify blocks
        $markup = $this->lines($lines);

        # trim line breaks
        $markup = trim($markup, "\n");

        return $markup;
    }
```

How can I use parsedown static ?

Comment: _Why_ would you want to use it static, when it is obviously not made for that?

Comment: Since I use all my classes static, it keeps an order on my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Parsedown class static with `instance()` function

```
echo Parsedown::instance()->text('Text');
```

Instance function code :

```
    static function instance($name = 'default')
    {
        if (isset(self::$instances[$name]))
        {
            return self::$instances[$name];
        }

        $instance = new static();

        self::$instances[$name] = $instance;

        return $instance;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you want to use a method static you should tell php you method was static At method definition for example in you case you can define you method like this :

```
public static function text($text)
{
    # make sure no definitions are set
    self::DefinitionData = array();

    # standardize line breaks
    $text = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $text);

    # remove surrounding line breaks
    $text = trim($text, "\n");

    # split text into lines
    $lines = explode("\n", $text);

    # iterate through lines to identify blocks
    $markup = self::lines($lines);

    # trim line breaks
    $markup = trim($markup, "\n");

    return $markup;
}
```

as you can see i user `Self::` instead of `$this->`
because in static function you cannot access to initialize data you need to define your public variable as static too

then you can use you function like this

```
Parsedown::text('text');
```

Comment: It doesn't work, but it helped me